# How to create a continuous v-slide-group with Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Has anyone managed to create a continuous v-slide-group with Vuetify? I've created this v-slide-group with custom arrows and all, but now i have to make it continuous - when the last item is reached (by clicking the green arrow, or swiping) it has to start over. I've saw that this functionality is implemented in the v-carousel component (along with the cycle prop), but is there a way to make it with v-slide-group?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a "working solution" right now, i'll be grateful if someone can expand on it, improve it or provide better one: I've v-model-ed the entire slide-group to a 0, and then when the user clicks the next arrow, it increments, previous arrow decrements. It takes 4 clicks to reach the end of the slide-group, so when `this.slideGroup == 4`, the next click sets it to 0 and restarts it.

```
slideGroup: 0,
nextSlide() {
  this.slideGroup++;
  this.slideGroup == 4 ? (this.slideGroup = 0) : "";
},
previousSlide() {
  this.slideGroup--;
}
```

Comment: Hi Futekov. I would love to know what your code looks like for this. I really need to implement this myself, and any help would really be appreciated. Did you build this into a method or hook, what exactly did you do here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what @Y.Futenov is doing. The template:

```
<v-slide-group v-model="slideGroup">
    <v-slide-item v-for="n in 25" :key="n">
        <v-btn>
            Options {{ n }}
        </v-btn>
    </v-slide-item>
</v-slide-group>
```

And your script for an autoplay slide show:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return { slideGroup: 0 }
    }
    ...
    created() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => slideGroup++, 2000)
    }
}
```

And it works!

Remember to clear the interval on the `beforeDestroy` life cycle event.